# How can I preprocess Storyboard/XIB files with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, preprocessor, xib

I need to preprocess my launch storyboard file to change its background color based on same build time configuration. I've added the following rule under Xcode Build Rules:

[image: build rule screenshot]

But I'm having some problems getting this to work. Actual script is fine.

First, the rule is not being executed. I guess if fails to match the file name. When I specify to match `*.storyboard`, it gets executed, but I do not want it matching all storyboard files, just that one. Of course, I could check the file name in the script itself.

Secondly, when it gets executed, it does not cause any side effects. I guess that the rules that follow, more specifically Storyboard compiler, fail to pick this file up. It might be that I'm using wrong file paths, or that my change is being overwritten with original file sometime later in the build process. Does anyone have more experience in this?

Comment: Launch screens are turned into image files and placed in the bundle. The actual storyboard is not run at runtime. Are you sure that you are applying your script before these images are generated?

Comment: My rule is processed first. Are you sure they get converted to images? Do you have any reference supporting that?

Comment: Build your app and look in the bundle that is created. you'll see launch images generated at multiple sizes and orientations from your launch storyboard.

Comment: I don't see any launch images in my bundle, yet I see compile storyboard file LaunchScreen.storyboardc...